# Is it possible to re enter to UK after get refused for the first time for visa-free passport holder?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-free-entry, malaysian-citizens

I got refused for the first time to enter the UK as what the UK immigration had these points out during my interview.

1. I had no ticket to embark from UK (which I told them that I will decide it once my sister had graduate on January 2019)
2. They said my financial is not stable (as I told them that my parents going to support and transfer the money as I reached UK)
3. My intention to visit UK is not clear (as I told them that I will stay with my sister for 3-4 months and we will go travel in a few places)

And for now, I had bought a ticket to go out from UK (to Cologne, for my next Europe trip before I go back to my home), I have 5000£, and I’m staying with my girlfriend for a month (apartment has been paid in full, which I have the tenancy agreement document ), my sister graduation invitation, my parents return flight ticket.

What should I prepare to go in UK tomorrow?

Comment: You’re in serious danger of a second refusal.

Comment: Why oh why not just buy a return ticket to your own country?  It will look less suspicious and the cost is nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. But as what I’ve been told, the officer said that “I don’t have tickets to embark from uk OR tickets to my home”. And that time I don’t have any but right now I have one of them which is to Cologne (to leave uk). I’m going to fly to my home country (malaysia) from Berlin after visiting. But as what I concerned, from Berlin, that’s not the uk’s problem anymore. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to re enter to UK after get refused for the first time for visa-free passport holder?

In general, when one is refused entry to the UK as a visa-free national, it is *recommended* that they subsequently obtain a visa prior to attempting a re-entry. While not a requirement, the entry refusal is a "black mark" on ones' record and a visa will "wipe clean" the record.

As mentioned, however, it is not a requirement: if you believe that you have addressed the issues that you were originally refused entry for, you are free to re-attempt a visa-free entry. You will, however, face stronger scrutiny at the border in the face of your previous refusal (especially since it sounds as though it was relatively recent.) Furthermore, if you are refused again, these black marks have a "compounding" effect, if only to cause the appearance of a person who is "desperate" to gain entry.

> What should I prepare to go in UK tomorrow?

You should bring with you the same documentation which you would submit for a visa application. This is general advice; most times when entering countries visa-free you won't be asked for it, but especially after a previous refusal you must be prepared to "make your case" as they say with strong evidence to back your claims. Broadly speaking, such documentation would include bank statements (to prove you can support yourself), proof of hotel bookings or other accommodation arrangements, travel or health insurance (as necessary), etc. You may refer to the UK Government's guidance for visa applications for a discrete list of documentation requirements. [Visitor: Supporting Documents Guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf)

In addition, you should also bring documentation that addresses the deficiencies in your initial entry application which caused your earlier refusal. You've indicated that you've addressed these deficiencies (eg. purchased a ticket to leave to Cologne, etc.), so you should bring with you documentation of these remedies.

As mentioned, of course, you will come under increased scrutiny when arriving since you *do* have a very recent refusal. If you are refused again, it is *highly* recommended that you apply for a Standard Visitor Visa before attempting again.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply. But I have some other questions regarding this. Do I really need to apply for a visitor visa even I’m holding a visa-free passport? And how long usually it takes to apply for that?

Comment: It is recommended (but not required) that you apply for a visa after a prior refusal. A visa will wipe clean the slate, as they say. Without the visa you will always be carrying the black mark of the previous refusal, which will cause your entry applications to be scrutinized more closely. Once you are successfully awarded a visa, future visa free entry is once again as if you never had the refusal.

Comment: Yes I would apply for visitor visa but does it going to overlap with my current visa-free status? Because as what I concerned, as Malaysian passport holder, we don’t need a visa to go in uk.

Comment: There is no such thing as "overlap" for this. You are a visa free national: that will not change unless your nationality changes or the UK decides that your country's citizens require visas (unlikely.) The entry refusal is a black mark on your record: future border crossings will be scrutinized more strongly because of this previous negative experience. After you successfully get a visa, the black mark will be gone and you will be able to go back to entering visa-free as easily as you had before (eg without the added scrutimy caused by the refusal.)